# URL gives Internal server error in production, but works in development?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony-2.2

I'm relatively new to symfony2 and doctrine2 and am puzzled by something...

When accessing a certain page in the `dev` environment, I get the content of the page as expected, but when I try to open the exact same page using the `prod` environment, all I am seeing is an "Internal Server Error".

Other pages in `prod` work fine by the way...

Looking at the php error log, I am seeing

> PHP Warning: require([path]/app/cache/prod/doctrine/orm/Proxies/_*CG*_SitesMyBundleEntity[myEntity].php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in [path]\vendor\doctrine\orm\lib\Doctrine\ORM\Proxy\ProxyFactory.php on line 92

Looking at the relevant directory, the mentioned proxy file is indeed not there, but others are.

I've tried completely clearing the cache directories to no avail, same applies to regenerating the entities.

Perhaps relevant: I've recently upgraded tot symfony 2.2 and its companion doctrine version.

Can anyone point me in the right direction as to why that specific proxy isn't created automatically (when others are) and what I can do to resolve this issue ?

[edit]
Even though the reflection error thrown when running `php app/console cache:warmup --env=prod` wasn't related to the entity for which the proxy file was missing, resolving the reflection error also resolved the "internal server error"

Comment: may be you should try php app/console cache:warmup and check if it gives any error

Comment: results in `Warming up the cache for the dev environment with debug true`.  Running the command with `--env=prod` results in a reflection error, but the error is not related to the entity. Will investigate the reflection error.

Comment: I too am getting this error: [ReflectionException]
  Class Name\Bundle\Entity\Name\Bundle\Entity\Order does not exist and should be Class Name\Bundle\Entity\Order does not exist. any one have any updates on this?

Answer (score -1):

Uncomment `auto_generate_proxy_classes: %kernel.debug%` in the config.yml.

Comment: Hi, thanks for putting an answer up. Can you give a bit more commentary on how your solution fixes the problem? remember that other n00bs are likely to read this question/answer, and might need to know how this solution works to tell if it's a good fit for them too. :)